# What is a "Graphical Table of Contents" Abstract?

Tags: research-process, publications

For one of my accepted papers, the publication editor sent me this note:

> AUTHOR: Please provide a short “Graphical Table of Contents”
>   abstract (maximum 80 words or 3 sentences) summarizing the key
>   findings presented in the paper for Table of Content (TOC) entry.

Can someone please explain what that means? I understand the bit about 80 words max abstract but I don't understand why it's tagged "graphical". Is it supposed to be illustrated?

Comment: Good question. I actually got this request as a reviewer of the paper. My review will be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some publishers (ACS I'm lookin at you) have what they call GToC, which is like a ToC with small images. You might have seen such in some magazines, here's [an example](http://www.spd.org/spd/images/SI-Apple-Tablet-Table-of-Contents.jpg).

Accompanying the image is usually a short text that is sort of like a teaser for the article, in a way the coolest tidbit about what you have written. I believe that's what they are asking for here.

Comment: For related discussion on this see *Full Text and Figure Display Improves Bioscience Literature Search* ([Divoli et al. 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0009619)).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I found a similar "teaser" on the journal's site as well. That's exactly what they are doing.